# Приведет ли данный код к утечке памяти?

Tags: c++, память

У меня есть следующий метод:

```
AllVerticesIter& Vertices() { return *(new AllVerticesIter(*this)); }
```

Где-то в другом месте программы:

```
GraphAsMatrix::AllVerticesIter it = directed.Vertices();
for(;!it.IsDone(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "\t[number: " << (*it).Number() << " | weight: " << (*it).weight << "]" << std::endl;
}

delete &it; // Aborted (core dumped)
```

При попытке удалить созданный методом `Vertices()` объект операционная система убивает процесс. Без `delete` все работает хорошо, но мне кажется, что в таком случае возникает утечка памяти. Нужно ли удалять объект `it` и, если да, как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Вообще-то вот тут `GraphAsMatrix::AllVerticesIter it = directed.Vertices();` выполняется копирование, так что адрес `&it` не совпадает с тем, что выделен через `new`, и вы получаете утечку памяти... Попробуйте `GraphAsMatrix::AllVerticesIter& it = directed.Vertices();`

Comment: Действительно, работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы руками вызываете new/delete, то скорее всгео вы что-то делаете неправильно.